# Does okular/poppler support following intra-document cross-references in PDF files?

Tags: pdf, user-interface, okular, poppler

Using docbook and Apache FOP I can create PDFs that contain cross-references. For example, the *Table of Contents* of a book looks like this:

```
 Chapter 1 Introduction........................12
```

Using the ancient `xpdf` I can click on the page number 12 and be taken to page 12. Whenever the pointer is on a cross-reference (also for references to figures, tables, sections, etc.) it turns from an arrow into a left-pointing hand to indicate "*click me to follow the reference*". `evince` can do the same.

For some reason, `okular` appears unable to do this. I tried left-middle-right clicks, with and without CTRL, ALT, SHIFT keys. Is this just a configuration snag? Or is okular in fact unable to follow cross-references?

I'm using "Okular 0.20.2 Using KDE Development Platform 4.14.2" on FreeBSD 11.

Comment: The short answer is yes, it does, but I don't have any idea why it wouldn't be working for you. There is a "draw border around links" setting (under "Accessibility") that would let you diagnose whether it was the interaction or the detection that was broken.

Comment: @MichaelHomer I've turned it on and it does indeed draw the borders around the links. What do you do to follow a link? Just left-click?

Comment: Yes. Right-click gives a one-item menu with a "Follow This Link" entry.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Hmm. Left-click does nothing. Middle-click enables continuous zooming. Right click brings up a 4-entry menu with the page number as the title and "Add Bookmark", "Fit Width", "Next Bookmark", "Previous Bookmark".

Comment: @MichaelHomer Solved it: You have to be in "Browse" mode; in "Zoom" mode or "Selection" mode following links is disabled/replaced by a different function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wasn't a configuration snag, but a user interface snag: following links works while using the "**Browse Tool**" (Icon: mouse), but not while using the "**Zoom Tool**" (Icon: Looking glass over paper sheet) or the "**Selection Tool**" (Icon: pencil in corner of frame).

Comment: Wow... same here. Seems like a bit of a user interface failure.